# How do I gain access to wireless network logs in iOS (iPad Pro)?

Tags: ios, ipad, network, wifi

I have an iPad pro that will connect to my 5GHz wireless network, gets an IP from the DHCP server (verified on the iPad and on the router itself), and then after 10-20 seconds it disconnects for no apparent reason. It repeats this in a cycle if I have auto-connect turned on. There are no error messages that I can see which would indicate the reason for the disconnect, and examining the logs from the wireless access point it appears that the iPad just decided to disconnect on its own. I have tried forgetting the network on the iPad and reconnecting. I have tried rebooting the device. All to no avail.

I am hoping I can enable logging on the iPad and determine the reason for the disconnect. This iPad is the sole Apple device I have. I do not have a Mac, so am unable to use XCode. How do I get to the logs? Is there any other way to determine what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I found this post: [How to capture iOS Console Logs on Windows PC - iOS 11 Compatible](https://www.utest.com/articles/how-to-capture-ios-console-logs-on-windows-pc)
- You can also google it: "ios log on windows"
- And perhaps **Charles** for iOS can help you to get through https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/ios/

Comment: Thanks! Using iOSLogInfo, I was able to capture and analyze the logs. As best as I can tell, it appears iOS doesn't like my 5GHz-only WAP, and is disconnecting because it also expects a 2.4GHz band with the same SSID. I'm somewhat flustered with Apple because the 5GHz-only setup is valid and works with all my other devices (and more secure in a highly populated area), but turning on the 2.4GHz radio as well has resolved the problem with iOS.